# React library for physical address localization

Tags: reactjs, localization, libraries, navigator

My team wants to implement a feature for physical addresses to be localized from navigator.language, for example, in the US this is a physical address:

**919 Stimple Ct, Fairbanks, Alaska 99712, USA**

in other countries like Italy, the address is:

**Rossi Gianni, VIA GARIBALDI 26, 70043 MONOPOLI BA, ITALIA**

and each country or region have a different format for physical address.

The thing is the address display is based on US physical address for the street number and name, the state, the city, and then is displayed in another screen. But for other countries is different, so the street number and name depends on how the user writes them, but the other fields for state, city and Postal Code will show with the US address format. Changing the input fields will do the same, changing the variables for each input means creating code for each language (not an option).

I've been searching for a library for `React` to format physical address but all I've found are libraries to parse the address in an object, but it doesn't format the address by location.

So I'm looking for a master who may know a library (or maybe a license to pay for) to format physical address by location.

We may use only 5 address format by continent if there is no library to localize them.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you need a library for? They're N separate _lines_ and you do not need to truly _understand_ them when _printing_ the address: just concatenate one line after he other. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: For physical addresses, the simplest thing is to leave it to the user to supply the complete address, as a single input field and, stored and retrieved as a single string.  Otherwise, you're diving into a very deep (and volatile) rathole of varying address formats and conventions across the world, which change at the whim of a government or postal service.